# I'm getting a sigabrt error when a certain collision is detected (iOS, SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sigabrt

I am currently building an iOS app in Objective-C. The idea of the app is that you have some sort of rocket ship navigating through an asteroid belt of sorts. It is played in portrait mode. There are two different kinds of asteroids. Normal ones that make you lose when you crash into them, and golden ones that you shoot at to get coins.

Now, the issue occurs when a collision is detected between the bullet and a gold asteroid. When a collision is detected between the player and a normal asteroid, all is well, and you lose. But when a collision is detected between a bullet and a gold asteroid, I receive a sigabrt error.

The code code that detects the collision is the following:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

if (collision == (playerCategory | asteroidCategory))
{
    [self player:(SKSpriteNode *)self.player didCollideWithAsteroid:(SKSpriteNode *)self.asteroid];
}

uint32_t collision2 = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

if (collision2 == (bulletCategory | goldAsteroidCategory))
{
    [self bullet:(SKSpriteNode *)self.bullet didCollideWithGoldAsteroid:(SKSpriteNode *)self.goldAsteroid];
}
}
```

The code that runs when "[self player:(SKSpriteNode *)self.player didCollideWithAsteroid:(SKSpriteNode *)self.asteroid];" is called is this:

```
- (void)player:(SKSpriteNode *)player didCollideWithAsteroid:(SKSpriteNode *)asteroid
{
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Explosion.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];


NSLog(@"Hit");
[self.player removeFromParent];
[self.asteroid removeFromParent];

SKAction *actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction * loseAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:0.5];
    SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:NO];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
}];

[self.asteroid runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[loseAction, actionMoveDone]]];
}
```

This is the code that runs when "[self bullet:(SKSpriteNode *)self.bullet didCollideWithGoldAsteroid:(SKSpriteNode *)self.goldAsteroid];" is called:

```
- (void)bullet:(SKSpriteNode *)bullet didCollideWithGoldAsteroid:(SKSpriteNode *)goldAsteroid
{
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"ding.m4a" waitForCompletion:NO]];
NSLog(@"Hit");
[self.bullet removeFromParent];
[self.goldAsteroid removeFromParent];
[self plusOneCoin];
}
```

I believe that should be enough information and code, but do not hesitate to ask me for more, I will post what is necessary.

Comment: Where does it crash exactly? Does it print the 2nd "Hit" to the log? Does it actually get into the bullet:didCollideWithGoldAsteriod method? You're casting to SKSpriteNode a lot which is normally a sign that you're trying to cast objects forcefully. Also, why isn't bullet being used in this method? Instead you're using self.bullet.

Normally when I get sigabrt messages it is because I try to run a delayed SKAction on a node which has already been removed from parent and garbage collected.

Comment: What does the error message say? Have you set an all exceptions break point?

Comment: @PaddyCollins It wasn't printing "hit" in the log, but while I was looking through there, I saw that there was an issue with the sound effect to play. I replaced it, and now it works. I used self.bullet because I'm using it as a class-wide variable. I don't know what was up with the sound effect, but since I replaced it, it doesn't crash anymore, and no sigabrt.

Comment: @sangony I looked into it, looking for a "hit" in the log, as Paddy had suggested, and saw that there was some kind of issue with the sound effect. I'm not sure what was up, but I replaced it, and it now works, and I can move on to fixing other bugs.

Comment: That's excellent. As a side note, try not using m4a files with SpriteKit as it can cause issues. Wav or caf files are a better choice.

Comment: That's most likely what happened, I'm now using an mp3 file (I couldn't get a wav, as I wanted) ad it works. Do you have any idea why SpriteKit doesn't like m4a files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked in the log, I saw that there was an issue with the sound effect "ding.m4a". I replaced it with another coin sound, and it now works. I'm not exactly sure what was up with the sound, but that was the issue.